# Calculate the differences of list elements using zipWith

Tags: list, haskell, tuples

I have to make a function called differences, where I calculate the difference of every pair with `zipWith` and put it in a list.

For example `differences [1..5] == [1, 1, 1, 1]`.

So `[2-1, 3-2, 4-3, 5-4] == [1, 1, 1, 1]`.

I thought of making list of tuples, like this:

```
[1..5] = [(1,2), (2,3), (3,4), (4,5)]
```

Then use list comprehesion like this:

```
[zipWith (-) a b | a <- y, b <- x]
```

where x is the first element of the tuple and y is the second.

The functions type is `differences :: Num a => [a] -> [a]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're nearly there - but `zipWith` itself returns a list, so you don't want to put that inside a list comprehension unless you want the result to be a list of lists (which you don't, here).

`zipWith (-)` is absolutely the right idea here - it takes 2 lists and gives a new list given by taking the difference between corresponding elements of the given lists. Your output list, in your case, is intended to be 1 element shorter than the one input list, and you want to use `zipWith (-)` on 2 lists which consist of:

- all elements of the given list, other than the first
- all elements of the given list, other than the last

Haskell already gives us convenient functions for these, namely [tail](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:tail) and [init](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:init).

So the function you're looking for is:

```
differences xs = zipWith (-) (tail xs) (init xs)
```

Note that this isn't ideal, because both `init` and `tail` will crash your program with an ugly runtime error if `xs` is empty. It makes sense to output an empty list if you present an empty list to this function (although you could argue it doesn't, since you will get an empty list from a singleton list), so you can avoid a runtime crash by defining the function via pattern matching to explicitly cater for the empty list:

```
differences [] = []
differences xs = zipWith (-) (tail xs) (init xs)
```

While personally I think this is fine, and very explicit, you don't actually need to use both `init` and `tail` - `zipWith` works just fine if presented with lists of unequal length, when it will simply trim the larger one down to size. So `differences xs = zipWith (-) (tail xs) xs` is a viable, and slightly terser, alternative.

Comment: I feel the `init`-less solution is tidier, especially because `init`, unlike `tail`, involves going through the whole list. In fact, I find it tempting to go even further style-wise and write `differences xs@(_:ys) = zipWith (-) ys xs`.

Comment: Using `drop 1` instead of `tail` would also eliminate the need to have a separate case for the empty list.

Comment: @4castle I suggest posting that as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Building off [Robin Zigmond's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55778501/1126841), the `Applicative` instance for functions works well here:

```
(f <*> g) xs == f xs (g xs)
```

so

```
differences = zipWith subtract <*> tail
```

(where `subtract = flip (-)`.)

Comment: Nice - especially as I actually tried to simplify it in exactly this way with `<*>`, but for some reason couldn't see how to get it in the correct form. (Admittedly I didn't think about it for too long...)

Answer (score 1):

[As 4castle suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55778450/calculate-the-differences-of-list-elements-using-zipwith#comment98229457_55778501), using `drop 1` instead of `tail` in [Robin Zigmond's second, `init`-less solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55778501/2751851) means we can omit the `[]` case, as `drop 1 [] = []` (unlike `tail []`, which leads to a runtime error):

```
differences xs = zipWith (-) (drop 1 xs) xs
```

To contrast with this solution with no explicit pattern deconstruction, I will mention a spelling using none of `init`, `tail` and `drop`:

```
differences xs@(_:ys) = zipWith (-) ys xs
```